# what is the best cloud computing platform for biopython?

Tags: python, cloud, bioinformatics

i'm currently working (as a senior project) building and implementing a bioinformatics web application to manipulate large data & some some complex work on them

i'm using biopython for it

what cloud computing platform is best and why?

thanks in advance

Comment: Look into Google App Engine and Amazon EC2

Comment: Google app engine is great , the new SDK is out now version 1.4.0 has some cool features but it has no support for C extensions ,i didnt try amazon though , i'm thinking about windows azure at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been experimenting with Amazon EC2 and [boto](https://code.google.com/p/boto/). So far, it has been a powerful but gentle introduction to cloud computing.